# Travel on expired I-94. Is return on automatic revalidation possible?

Tags: h1b-visas

There are many cases where an extension to an H1B is filed and the I-94 has expired. Can a person travel to Canada and Mexico and come back using "Automatic Revalidation"?

Comment: Automatic revalidation requires a valid I-94.  Is there any reason why you think this might be an exception?

Comment: Automatic Revalidation is a process that is used when the VISA has expired, but the I-94 is still valid.  That said, this question really belongs on Expats rather than here as it regarding re-entering the US on a work visa.